# Extract multiple sub-strings from a string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have string which has a fix length of 14... and the string consist numbers from 0 to 9 ... now i have to extract 3 different sub strings from that where 1st substring will have 1st 2 chars then 2nd sub string will have next 6 chars and last sub string will have last 6 chars.. eg.

```
string =  "12345678901234";

substr1 =" 12";
substr2 = "345678";
substr3 = "901234";
```

like this... any one help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string str = "12345678901234";

string str1 = string.Empty;
string str2 = string.Empty;
string str3 = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    if (i < 2)
        str1 += str[i];
    else if (i > 1 && i < 8)
        str2 += str[i];
    else
        str3 += str[i];
}
```

Comment: Pretty poor answer, inefficient, more lines of code than necessary.

Comment: i'm also new..i don't have much idea about all the methods like Substring()..i was just trying to help..

Comment: thanks this is what i was looking for ... i can use substring but i didn't want it ... sorry for not telling that in question .. i am very open to any criticism so i dont mind ... thanks again @dotnet_nob

Comment: Well that worked out surprisingly well! :-) @Drone why didn't you mention this requirement in your question? In the context of not using `string.Substring`, this is a fairly reasonable answer actually. There's just pretty much no good reason not to use `string.Substring` unless it's an academic exercise.

Comment: @tomfanning no its not academic :D i just wanted something different bcoz my current project is not very challenging so i am trying different things on that ..

Answer (score 2):

**[C# Substring Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)**

```
string x  =  "12345678901234";
MessageBox.Show(x.Substring(0, 2)); // sub1
MessageBox.Show(x.Substring(2, 6)); // sub2
MessageBox.Show(x.Substring(8, 6)); // sub3
```